# TypeScript transpiling error with Webstorm 7

Tags: compiler-errors, typescript, code-translation

I've been developing TypeScript with Webstorm 7 for a while now, and today I get this error message which prevents Webstorm from transpiling ts files. Have anyone seen this problem before? By the way, I am on Mac.

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc --sourcemap MyClass.ts --module AMD --target ES5
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc.js:44963
                    if (decl.kind == 32 /* DynamicModule */) {
                            ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined
    at SemanticInfoChain.findDecls (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc.js:44963:33)
    at SemanticInfoChain.findSymbol (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc.js:45040:30)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc.js:37104:52
    at PullTypeResolver.findTypeSymbolForDynamicModule (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc.js:36426:30)
    at PullTypeResolver.resolveImportDeclaration (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc.js:37103:36)
    at PullTypeResolver.resolveAST (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc.js:39157:33)
    at PullTypeResolver.resolveList (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc.js:38618:26)
    at PullTypeResolver.resolveAST (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc.js:39132:33)
    at PullTypeResolver.resolveModuleDeclaration (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc.js:36610:30)
    at PullTypeResolver.resolveAST (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc.js:39138:33)
```

Comment: Are you saying doing the same compilation from the console works?

Comment: Figured it out. This error occurs when I import an empty class, I must have a long day :( Thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the latest version of TypeScript. I haven't experienced this error with webstorm.

PS: you can try to use a slightly older version of TypeScript :

```
npm install -g  typescript@0.9.1
```